# drag and drop objects between two scenes in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two scenes, scene1 and scene2. For dragging I have tried with three js draggable but it did not allow me to drag objects outside of scene1. I need to drag objects from scene1 and drop it to scene2.I have attached an image of it. Thanks in Advance.

**[The image with two scenes]**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Draggable" in three.js simple means you can transform an object within the space where it exists. To move it between scenes, you would need to view it more as a transaction.

1. Mousedown on the item you want to drag
2. Save a reference to the object (`var tempobj = selectedObj;`)
3. Start dragging
4. Detect when your cursor exits the first viewport
5. Remove the object from scene 1 (`scene1.remove(tempobj);`)
6. Detect when your cursor enters the second viewport
7. Add the object to scene 2 (`scene2.add(tempobj);`)
8. Continue dragging the object until you mouse-up

Comment: I don't think it will work. Point # 3, Start Dragging - If you drag an object, it will still remain within the scene it exists. But the question is, dragging from one scene to another.

Comment: @Jay Correct. That's why you remove it from the first scene in step 5, and add it to the second scene in step 7. Note: I don't say to detect when you left the first _scene_, but when the cursor exits the first _view_. I'll clarify this in my answer.

Comment: @Jim, Step 5 & Step 7 comes only after Step 3. You are stuck in Step 3 itself, the dragging will no longer be there. Adding and removing object is fine, but dragging will not imitate. Had it been - one mouse click, add object in Scene2 and another mouse click remove object from Scene1, there would be no problem at all. The question is dragging object from Scene1 and dropping into Scene 2.

Comment: @Jay `THREE.Scene` represents infinite euclidian space. I've no idea how  you can "drag something out of a scene". This question is simply... well it makes no sense, and needs editing. Jim should be given a medal for taking the time and effort to write this answer, not doubted like this.

Comment: `You are stuck in Step 3 itself, the dragging will no longer be there. Adding and removing object is fine, but dragging will not imitate.` No. You are wrong, and yes it will.

Comment: Matter of coincidence, even I am looking for a solution to this. In fact many people should be curious for a solution to this, for which we get into Stackoverflow. Do you have a solution with code, fiddle anything?